# Configuring POP3 access on Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, pop3

I'm trying to setup POP3 access on our Exchange 2013 server. As of right now I've enabled both the POP3/POP3 backend. Both services are running. I've also enabled PlainTextLogin. I'm able to telnet to port 110 of the server, but when I try to login I receive -ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. I've tried restarting both services to no avail.

POP settings are as follows.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-PopSettings | fl


RunspaceId                        : 44653048-8831-43e7-ab8c-ece38b6143a1
Name                              : 1
ProtocolName                      : POP3
MaxCommandSize                    : 512
MessageRetrievalSortOrder         : Ascending
UnencryptedOrTLSBindings          : {[::]:110, 0.0.0.0:110}
SSLBindings                       : {[::]:995, 0.0.0.0:995}
InternalConnectionSettings        : {mailserver.mydomain.local:995:SSL, mailserver.mydomain.local:110:TLS}
ExternalConnectionSettings        : {}
X509CertificateName               : email.mydomain.com
Banner                            : The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
LoginType                         : PlainTextLogin
AuthenticatedConnectionTimeout    : 00:30:00
PreAuthenticatedConnectionTimeout : 00:01:00
MaxConnections                    : 2147483647
MaxConnectionFromSingleIP         : 2147483647
MaxConnectionsPerUser             : 16
MessageRetrievalMimeFormat        : BestBodyFormat
ProxyTargetPort                   : 9955
CalendarItemRetrievalOption       : iCalendar
OwaServerUrl                      :
EnableExactRFC822Size             : False
LiveIdBasicAuthReplacement        : False
SuppressReadReceipt               : False
ProtocolLogEnabled                : False
EnforceCertificateErrors          : False
LogFileLocation                   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\Pop3
LogFileRollOverSettings           : Daily
LogPerFileSizeQuota               : 0 B (0 bytes)
ExtendedProtectionPolicy          : None
EnableGSSAPIAndNTLMAuth           : True
Server                            : MAILSERVER
AdminDisplayName                  :
ExchangeVersion                   : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
DistinguishedName                 : CN=1,CN=POP3,CN=Protocols,CN=MAILSERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative
                                    Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=First
                                    Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=local
Identity                          : MAILSERVER\1
Guid                              : 27c9dd2e-e508-41f1-b8bd-024926bb9273
ObjectCategory                    : mydomain.local/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Protocol-Cfg-POP-Server
ObjectClass                       : {top, protocolCfg, protocolCfgPOP, protocolCfgPOPServer}
WhenChanged                       : 8/1/2013 5:17:10 PM
WhenCreated                       : 6/10/2013 10:52:09 PM
WhenChangedUTC                    : 8/2/2013 12:17:10 AM
WhenCreatedUTC                    : 6/11/2013 5:52:09 AM
OrganizationId                    :
OriginatingServer                 : sqlserver.mydomain.local
IsValid                           : True
ObjectState                       : Unchanged



[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you logging in? Can you post a screenshot of your telnet session?

Comment: I would rather not screenshot it for security reasons, but I'm telneting to port 110, typing 'USER administrator', then 'PASS mypassword' and then the server responds with '-ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password'. I've also tried doing so with the user set to 'mydomain\administrator'.

Comment: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ - POP email test, post edited results in your question.

Comment: You can't connect via POP/IMAP with the Administrator account. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657728(v=exchg.150).aspx#nonstandardaccounts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As joeqwerty said, you cannot login through the administrator account.